# Buscar Produtos via API ou Web Crawler

Tags: api

Pretendo desenvolver um software que exiba informações de produtos. Gostaria de saber se os grandes ecommerce utilizados aqui no Brasil (americanas, walmart, submarino, extra) disponibilizam alguma API para buscarmos as informações de seus produtos.

Uma outra dúvida. Seria errado eu desenvolver um robô (web crawler, spider, etc) para buscar estas informações? Por exemplo, um software que acesse o site da Americanas, entre em determinado produto, pegue as informações que preciso e armazene em minha base de dados? Digamos que quando eu for exibir a informação que eu obtive da Americanas, eu faça um link para o site deles contendo o produto. Isto talvez seja até bom para eles.

Comment: Alberto bem vindo ao StackOverflow! Considere alterar a sua pergunta para ficar mais clara. O que você deseja saber? Não é errado consumir uma API desde que você tenha a permissão para consumir a mesma. Vale lembrar também que algumas APIs possuem limites de chamadas e algumas restrições com a utilização dos dados disponibilizados por elas.

Comment: Nada impede você de desenvolver um robô (web crawler, tecnicamente falando), afinal seria o mesmo que uma pessoa acessando o site em sua parte pública, mesmo que sites de buscas fazem para indexar conteúdos. Atualmente existe uma empresa brasileira que fatura milhões de reais realizando sob demanda varredura nas principais lojas por produtos e seus preços assim a loja que contratou a busca identifica se precisa baixar seus preços ou se tem margem para subi-los, de uma forma bem mais prática.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Os grandes ecommerce utilizados aqui no Brasil (americanas, walmart, submarino, extra) disponibilizam alguma API para buscarmos informações de produtos?

A única API que encontrei de busca de produtos no Brasil foi a do Buscapé,  que você pode acessar [aqui](http://developer.buscape.com.br/portal).

As API's de outras empresas é voltada para o [Marketplace](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-marketplace) e os produtos que podem ser listados são apenas os que o usuário cadastrou via API.

> Seria errado criar um robô para buscar estas informações?

Se você for usar alguma API e nos termos de uso, ou na documentação está claro que é proibido então não é permitido criar.

API da B2W(Americanas, Submarino, Shoptime) [aqui](https://api-sandbox.bonmarketplace.com.br/docs/).

API CNova (Extra, Casas Bahia, Ponto frio, Cdiscount, Barateriro e  Partiu Viagens) [aqui](https://desenvolvedores.cnova.com/api-portal/).

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações. Quando falo robô, queria dizer um programa, que seria feito por mim, sem o uso de uma API, que acesse o site, por exemplo, da americanas e busque os produto e as informações que preciso. Vi que o buscape começou desta forma até conseguir que os lojistas disponibilizassem estas informações.

Comment: @Alberto entendi que você ia fazer o robô consultar os dados via API. Vou pesquisar, caso encontre vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: Outra API é a do Mercado Livre: http://developers.mercadolibre.com

Answer (score 1):

Você já procurou no [99apis](http://99apis.com/card/mercado-livre-developers)? Acho que lá é o melhor lugar pra encontrar qualquer API. Inclusive, lá tem o da [B2W](http://99apis.com/card/b-on-marketplace) e da [CNova](http://99apis.com/card/cnova-marketplace-api), que são as que você procura, como nosso colega @adelmo00 falou em sua resposta.

Fica a dica pra quem for procurar outras APIs por aí.